# Cannot instantiate delphi written application.exe using IIS, MVC4, C# and COM

Tags: asp.net, delphi, iis, com, iis-8

My web application is a web interface for a desktop application called MyApplication.exe. My web application is written in C# (MVC4) that communicates with the MyApplication.exe (written in delphi) via COM-Objects.

When 16 clients invoke the web app via the browser, 16 MyApplication.exe instances will be created on the server:

[image: Task-Manager]

My Problem: if client number 17 invokes the web application, I get the following exception in my eventlog:

**"System Error. Code: 8. Not enough storage is available to process this command."**

The process explorer indicates, that the worker process w3wp.exe consumes ~600 MB memory, but the machine has 4 GB RAM.

Note: The created instances will be saved in sessions (inProc).

Im am Using:

1. MVC4
2. ASP.NET CLR 4.0
3. IIS 8
4. Windows Server 2012 R2 (also occurs on Windows 8.1)
5. 4GB RAM

**I tried the following things:**

1. Create instances locally via a VB-Script using COM-Objects. Result: I am able to create ~50 instances of MyApplication.exe with no problems.
2. Adapted the machine.config using the following entry:

   processModel enable="true" memoryLimit="100"

Result: After restarting the worker process, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Pro tip: check the number of threads/handles you are using....

Comment: @whosrdaddy: can you please specify you comment? What threads, where can I check the number of threads and where can I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the user IIS is running under this could be a problem where the non-interactive desktop heap size is an issue.  I've ran into this problem involving windows services.

When you run your test application most likely you are running under a different user.  You can try adjusting the non-interactive desktop heap size in the registry to see if it resolves this issue:

Below is taken from [KB 126962](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126962)

> To correct this problem, increase the size of the desktop heap: Run
>   Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe). From the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE subtree,
>   go to the following key: \System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\SubSystems Select the Windows value. From the Edit menu,
>   choose String. Increase the SharedSection parameter.
>
> For Windows NT: SharedSection specifies the system and desktop heaps
>   using the following format: SharedSection=xxxx,yyyy Add ",256" or
>   ",512" after the yyyy number.
>
> For Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003: SharedSection
>   uses the following format to specify the system and desktop heaps:
>   SharedSection=xxxx,yyyy,zzzz For 32-bit operating systems, increase
>   the yyyy value to "12288"; Increase the zzzz value to "1024". For
>   64-bit operating systems, increase the yyyy value to "20480"; Increase
>   the zzzz value to "1024".

Here is also a similar article for windows vista / 7 [KB 947246](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947246)

Comment: On my Windows 8.1 machine, I set ´SharedSection=2048,20480,2048´ and it works now. So much thanks!