# How can I change SharedSection in registry using C#?

Tags: c#, regex, registry

Regarding [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326851/cannot-instantiate-delphi-written-application-exe-using-iis-mvc4-c-sharp-and-c) in my registry `System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\SubSystems` I have to change in value `windows` > string parameter `SharedSection=SharedSection=1024,20480,768` the third value from **768** into **2048**.

What is the best way to do that via C#?

I tried the following:

```
var myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\SubSystems").GetValue("Windows");
```

The local variable `myKey` contains the following string:

```
"C:\\Windows\\system32\\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768 Windows=On SubSystemType=Windows ServerDll=basesrv,1 ServerDll=winsrv:UserServerDllInitialization,3 ServerDll=sxssrv,4 ProfileControl=Off MaxRequestThreads=32"
```

Do I need to change the value **768** into **2048** using regular expressions or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
try {
    updateSharedSection(-1, -1, 2048);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    //..
}
```

- first param the maximum size of the system-wide heap
- second param the size of each desktop heap
- third param the size of the desktop heap that is associated with a non-interactive Windows station.

...

```
public void updateSharedSection(int z)
{
    updateSharedSection(-1, -1, z);
}

public void updateSharedSection(int x, int y, int z)
{
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\SubSystems", true);
    key.SetValue("Windows", _sharedSection(x, y, z, key.GetValue("Windows").ToString()));
}

/// <param name="x">the maximum size of the system-wide heap (in kilobytes) / -1 by default</param>
/// <param name="y">the size of each desktop heap / -1 by default</param>
/// <param name="z"> the size of the desktop heap that is associated with a non-interactive Windows station / -1 by default</param>
/// <param name="raw">raw data line</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string _sharedSection(int x, int y, int z, string raw)
{
    Func<int, string, string> setVal = delegate(int xyz, string def) {
        return (xyz == -1) ? def : xyz.ToString();
    };

    return Regex.Replace(raw, @"SharedSection=(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)", delegate(Match m)
    {
        return string.Format(
            "SharedSection={0},{1},{2}", 
                setVal(x, m.Groups[1].Value),
                setVal(y, m.Groups[2].Value),
                setVal(z, m.Groups[3].Value));
    }, 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```