# How can I change SharedSection in registry using NSIS?

Tags: registry, nsis

Regarding to [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382462/how-can-i-change-sharedsection-in-registry-using-c) in need to implement this functionality for a nsis update.

In the registry `System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\SubSystems` I have to change the `windows` > string parameter `SharedSection=1024,20480,768` value.
The third value **768** needs to be increased up to **1536**.

With the basic `WriteRegStr` and `ReadRegStr` functions i am not able to do this.

Comment: You should be really careful when modifying these values, if you make a mistake the system might not boot.

Answer (score 2):

The registry functions cannot perform string manipulation. If you need to manipulate a string you can take a look at some of the helper macros that ship with NSIS or write your own.

I ended up with a hybrid that does a bit of both:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include StrFunc.nsh
${StrLoc}

Section

ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems" "Windows"

${StrLoc} $7 $0 "SharedSection=" ">" ; Find "SharedSection="
StrCpy $R1 $0 $7 ; Save the stuff before "SharedSection="
StrCpy $R2 $0 "" $7
${StrLoc} $8 $R2 " " ">" ; Find the end of "SharedSection=#,#,#" by looking for a space
${IfThen} $8 = 0 ${|} StrLen $8 $R2 ${|}
StrCpy $R3 $R2 "" $8 ; Save the stuff after "SharedSection=#,#,#"
StrCpy $R2 $0 $8 $7 ; Save "SharedSection=#,#,#"
; We can now parse "SharedSection=#,#,#":
StrLen $8 $R2
findcomma:
    IntOp $8 $8 - 1
    StrCpy $1 $R2 1 $8
    StrCmp $1 "," findcomma_end
    StrCmp $1 "" findcomma_end findcomma
findcomma_end:
IntOp $9 $8 + 1
StrCpy $2 $R2 "" $9
${If} $1 != "" ; Only edit if we found the comma..
${AndIf} $2 != "" ; ..And there was something after the comma
    StrCpy $R2 $R2 $8 ; Copy the first part of the string
    StrCpy $R2 "$R2,1536" ; Append the final comma and number
${EndIf}
StrCpy $0 "$R1$R2$R3" ; Build the final string

DetailPrint Result=$0
# TODO: WriteRegStr HKLM "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems" "Windows" $0

SectionEnd
```